# Apply a polygon filter to CartoJS 4 dataview

Tags: carto-js

Checking this example on CartoJS 4 documentation https://carto.com/developers/carto-js/examples/#example-filter-data-using-drawing-tools, you can apply a circle filter to a **source**. The problem with this is affects what the user is seeing on the loaded layer. There is a way to apply the same filter but to a **dataview**? That way the user can draw polygons on top of the layer to get the data without affecting the visible layer. So far the examples only shows how to apply 'bounding box' filters to a dataview.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply a polygon filter, but you can run a query against SQL API to get data from a random polygon.

Here an example: https://bl.ocks.org/alasarr/e80378614d4290b970cf25ccdb17c377

At the example, you've a layer of points, you can draw a polygon and query data that match with your polygon.

Comment: I have already poly queries using the sql api. Weird and absurd they make a new cartojs library adding rectangle filters but left out the poly and circle capabilities. I needed the poly filter inside the library because when a rect filter is applied, it also consider other filters already in place. using the sql api forces me to track all those filters outside of the cartojs.

Comment: That’s true but I usually prefer to have the flexibility of SQL because I can do almost everything that I want in term of filters.

Comment: Sometimes functionality is preferred over flexibility. :)